# What is the alternative to takeFirst method

Tags: observable, rx-android, rx-java3

I am new to RxAndroid, that's why referring to all the operators of Rx. I have found out that `observable.takeFirst()` is showing redline as it could not be found in RxJava3. Can anyone tell me what is the alternative to `takefirst()` method?

Answer (score 3):

`takeFirst` was removed in RxJava 2. Use `filter(predicate).take(1)`.